# Using Namespace in Qt 5.4

Tags: c++, widget, qt-creator, qt5.4

I got a issue in GraphicsList.cpp in Qt 5.4

```
#include "GraphicsList.h"

GraphicsList::GraphicsList()
{
    _DesignLayerList=new QList<WorkSystem::GraphicShape>();
}
void GraphicsList::Draw(){
    for(int i=this->_DesignLayerList->count();i>=0;--i){

        WorkSystem::GraphicShape shapeObject=(WorkSystem::GraphicShape)_DesignLayerList[i];
        //        WorkSystem::GraphicShape shapeObject=_DesignLayerList[i];
        shapeObject.Draw();
    }
}
```

> QQQ/GraphicsList.cpp:9: error: no matching conversion for C-style cast
>   from 'QList' to 'WorkSystem::GraphicShape'
>           WorkSystem::GraphicShape shapeObject=(WorkSystem::GraphicShape)_DesignLayerList[i];
>                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

My GraphicList.h

```
#ifndef GRAPHICSLIST_H
#define GRAPHICSLIST_H

#include "GraphicShape.h"

class GraphicsList
{
public:
    GraphicsList();
    ~GraphicsList();
    void Draw();

private:
    QList<WorkSystem::GraphicShape> *_DesignLayerList;
};

#endif // GRAPHICSLIST_H
```

my GraphicShap.h

```
#ifndef GRAPHICSHAPE_H
#define GRAPHICSHAPE_H
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPainter>
namespace WorkSystem {

class GraphicShape
{
public:
    GraphicShape();
    ~GraphicShape();
    QColor _penColor;
     virtual void Draw();
};

}


#endif // GRAPHICSHAPE_H
```

My GraphicShape.cpp

```
#include "GraphicShape.h"
#include <QDebug>
WorkSystem::GraphicShape::GraphicShape()
{
    _penColor=Qt::white;
}

void WorkSystem::GraphicShape::Draw(){
    qDebug()<<"DrawDrawDrawDraw";


}

WorkSystem::GraphicShape::~GraphicShape()
{

}
```

Please give me any suggestion.

shapeLine.h

```
#ifndef SHAPELINE_H
#define SHAPELINE_H
#include <QDebug>
#include "GraphicShape.h"
namespace WorkSystem {

class shapeLine : public GraphicShape
{
public:
    shapeLine();
    ~shapeLine();
protected:
    void Draw();
};
}
#endif // SHAPELINE_H
```

shapeLine.cpp
...

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be a bit of a misuse of pointers. If you look at the declaration for your `_DesignLayerList` member:

```
QList<WorkSystem::GraphicShape> *_DesignLayerList;
```

You are not declaring an actual `QList` instance. Instead, you are declaring a *pointer* to a QList. Thus when you use `_DesignLayerList[i]`, you aren't actually trying to look into the list, but instead doing pointer arithmetic to look up another `QList` instance, which is not what you are expecting.

Instead, you should declare your member variable without the star, meaning will be an actual instance of a `QList` rather than a pointer to a `QList`:

```
QList<WorkSystem::GraphicShape> _DesignLayerList;
```

This will then function as expected. I would also recommend reviewing your understanding of the difference between pointers and values, as this is a fundamental of C++. In modern C++, it is recommended to avoid the use of raw pointers as much as possible and instead use smart pointers, references, and value types as they are generally more appropriat and safer.

An alternative, if you insist on using pointers, is to perform a lookup by first de-referencing the pointer so you are referring to the `QList` instance it points to. However, I would not recommend this as it adds overhead and additional complexity for no benefit:

```
shapeObject = (*DesignLayerList)[i]
```

As an example of the problems common to using raw pointers like this: while you create the `QList` instance, you never actually delete it and as such this code leaks memory.

Comment: Thnkds^^. But your recommemd  "shapeObject = (*DesignLayerList)[i]" must lost some word? shpapObject is a Object. *DesignLayerList is a pointer type for some Object "[i]".

Comment: There are some error occur in `(WorkSystem::GraphicShape)_DesignLayerList[i]` when my code is running. `WorkSystem::GraphicShape shapeObject2;
    _DesignLayerList.push_back(shapeObject2);
    for(int i=this->_DesignLayerList.count();i>=0;--i){
        WorkSystem::GraphicShape shapeObject=(WorkSystem::GraphicShape)_DesignLayerList[i];
     }`

Comment: I am an idiot. I should use "i=this->_DesignLayerList.count()-1". NOT "i=this->_DesignLayerList.count()".

Comment: By the way, why can't i use " WorkSystem::shapeLine QQ;" when I using namespace WorkSystem in GraphList? Does I lost something?

Comment: As you see, GraphicShape has many subclass to inherit . ex. shapeLine,... .If I use " `QList<WorkSystem::GraphicShape> _DesignLayerList;`", then all item in _DesignLayerList are WorkSystem::GraphicShape. But that is not what I want. I want to pull shapeLine, GraphicShape,... e.t.c to _DesignLayerList. And draw by their true class event.

Comment: My current solution is using "`QList<WorkSystem::GraphicShape *> _DesignLayerList;`".Does it right?